# Mail Tracking in Exchange Server Using java api

Tags: exchange-server

i have to develop a application in java to track the mail of Exchange server. tracking like 
received message time, delete time and generate a month ally Repoart .
  **is mail tracking possible in Exchange server like gmail**

Answer (score 0):

Java API for Exchange.

[Find message tracking report](http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebservices/tutorial/findmessagetrackingreport.html)